# How to change ARKit node to something different

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I need some help to implement a custom node into my `ARKit` scene. I am using `ARSCNFaceGeometry` for a mask node to move around. I need some help to implement a custom image or a node rather than using Apple's mask node.  Thank you for your help.

```
var maskNode: Mask?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    self.sceneView.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
    self.sceneView.rendersContinuously = true
    if let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(),
    let geo = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device) {
        self.maskNode = Mask(geometry: geo)
        self.sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(self.maskNode!)
        self.maskNode?.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
        self.maskNode?.isHidden =  true
    }
    let config = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
    config.worldAlignment = .gravity
    session.delegate = self
    session.run(config, options: [])
    self.updateUI()
}
```

Mask:

```
class Mask: SCNNode, VirtualFaceContent {

    init(geometry: ARSCNFaceGeometry) {
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        geometry.firstMaterial = material
        super.init()
        self.geometry = geometry
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("\(#function) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: VirtualFaceContent

    /// - Tag: SCNFaceGeometryUpdate
    func update(withFaceAnchor anchor: ARFaceAnchor) {
        let faceGeometry = geometry as! ARSCNFaceGeometry
        faceGeometry.update(from: anchor.geometry)
    }
}
```

VirtualFaceContent:

```
protocol VirtualFaceContent {
    func update(withFaceAnchor: ARFaceAnchor)
}

typealias VirtualFaceNode = VirtualFaceContent & SCNNode

// MARK: Loading Content

func loadedContentForAsset(named resourceName: String) -> SCNNode {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resourceName, withExtension: "scn", subdirectory: "Models.scnassets")!
    let node = SCNReferenceNode(url: url)!
    node.load()
    return node
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about your issue? As your question currently is worded, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve or whether something is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use renderer(node: for anchor:). Guard check if the anchor is an ARFaceAnchor and then assign your custom geometry to that node. You can also just add your custom node to the node ARKit added for the anchor, up to you.